# Getting counts of 0 from a query with a double group by

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I'm trying to write a query that gets the counts for a table (call it item) categorized by two different things, call them type and code.  What I'm hoping for as output is the following:

```
Type Code Count
1    A    3
1    B    0
1    C    10
2    A    0
2    B    13
2    C    2
```

And so forth.

Both type and code are found in lookup tables, and each item can have just one type but more than one code, so there's also a pivot (aka junction or join) table for the codes.  I have a query that can get this result:

```
Type Code Count
1    A    3
1    C    10
2    B    13
2    C    2
```

and it looks like (with join conditions omitted):

```
SELECT typelookup.name, codelookup.name, COUNT(item.id)
FROM typelookup
LEFT OUTER JOIN item JOIN itemcodepivot 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN codelookup
GROUP BY typelookup.name, codelookup.name
```

Is there any way to alter this query to get the results I'm looking for?  This is in MySQL, if that matters.  I'm not actually sure this is possible all in one query, but if it is I'd really like to know how.  Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `CROSS JOIN` between `typelookup` and `codelookup` should solve this problem:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name, COUNT(item.id)
FROM typelookup t
CROSS JOIN codelookup c
LEFT JOIN itemCodePivot icp ON icp.codeId = c.codeId
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.itemId = icp.itemId AND i.TypeId = t.TypeId
GROUP BY t.name, c.name
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work... I get the same counts repeated, like 1 A = 2 A = 3 A, 1 B = 2 B = 3 B. And none of them are 0.

Comment: This should work in theory... if you're not getting any rows with a count of 0, something else is going wrong.  Are you filtering out items in your `where` clause instead of your `join on` clauses?

Comment: The only thing in my WHERE clause is checking that both the type and code are active (t.active > 0 and c.active > 0 to be specific). It's otherwise exactly as you typed.

Comment: @Maltiriel I think I see the issue... see my updated query... I added another condition to the `join` to `item`.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use cross join for this?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT typelookup.name, codelookup.name, COUNT(item.id)
FROM codelookup CROSS JOIN typelookup
LEFT OUTER JOIN item JOIN itemcodepivot 
GROUP BY typelookup.name, codelookup.name
```

Cross join should get all types joined with all codes.. Hard to make correct SQL when you don't have all the table declarations but you can give it a try..

Comment: I'm trying this, but I keep getting syntax errors.  I don't know if I'm mistyping over and over or if there's some syntax for CROSS JOIN I'm getting wrong or what. ETA What other table declarations would you need?

Comment: Finally got my syntax errors resolved, and now I just get the same count for everything.

Comment: Can you paste the entire query as you have it now?

Answer (score 0):

Note, that you should substitute your actual JOIN conditions instead of using mine.

```
SELECT tl.name, cl.name, IFNULL(COUNT(i.id),0)
FROM typelookup tl 
LEFT JOIN item i ON tl.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN itemcodepivot icp ON icp.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN codelookup cl ON cl.id = icp.codelookup_id
GROUP BY tl.name, cl.name;
```

Try this and see how your counts look.

I'm not understanding your need for a RIGHT JOIN on codelookup.  If this (edit) doesn't give you what you want, try adding that back in.

Comment: Yes, I said that I omitted the join conditions.  They are there in the real query.  The actual tables are large and have a ton of other stuff in them.  I've given the only columns that are actually relevant to this query though.  What else do you need to know? Again as I said the query I wrote finds the counts just fine as long as there is an item with a specified type and code.

Comment: Changing to inner joins gives the same results as my original query.

Comment: Alas, that again gives the same results.  As does putting the RIGHT OUTER JOIN back in.  I put that in there for the same reason there's a LEFT OUTER JOIN between typelookup and item; I want to keep the values from those lookup tables even if no items match them.  That was the theory anyhow.  In practice since all the values of each lookup table do occur at least once in the results (but each combination of the two does not occur at least once) the OUTER JOINs don't actually help in the way I was hoping they would.

Comment: @Maltiriel give the solutions provided by Michael or barsju a shot; looks like they both agree on attacking this from a different direction.